# How do I get the current path alias or path?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

How can I get the current alias and/or path in Drupal 8?

In Drupal 7 I did this with [`drupal_get_path_alias()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7). What is the equivalent code I should use in Drupal 8?

Comment: +1 upvote. Answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/232242/1082 below here on this same page works in Drupal 9 - 9.0.7 I have found.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Some of the other answers were only correct during previous alpha/beta versions of **Drupal 8**, or seemed to be incomplete. As of beta7 (and hopefully permanently), the following rules should apply:

For the current raw **path** (the un-aliased **Drupal** path):

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
```

For the current **URI**, which is pretty-much a direct representation of the request (it may even include a query string):

```
$current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
```

There is of course no guarantee that this `$current_uri` value will give you an alias, even if one is available for the request, as it only represents what the user has requested. So to strictly do what you are asking about (get alias if available, and path if not) I think you could do:

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$result = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
```

Of course, depending on the type of processing you are doing it may be best to be working with routes instead of paths, but I suppose that's a whole other topic.

Comment: why you mention that it would be better to use routes instead of paths ? Can you provide a brief example/reason ?

Comment: @darol100, I may not be the best person to provide a comprehensive answer for that, but I can tell you that the use of paths for programmatic URL generation is officially depreciated in Drupal 8 - see: https://www.drupal.org/node/2046643. Symfony routes provide a more robust way to map resources independent of the path structures (if you build a link using routes, that link will keep working even if the URL path/pattern changes).

Comment: Just a note that `::getAliasByPath()` will no longer accept a path string without a leading slash (since beta13 I believe).

Comment: `getAliasByPath` does return the path without language prefix. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I agree about the route name subject. For example, if you want to check if you're in the /user/xxx url, it would be better to use : 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202831/get-the-route-name-of-the-current-page > if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === 'entity.user.canonical') than checking the path.

Answer (score 40):

The proper way for the url without the URL alias.

```
\Drupal::request()->attributes->get('_system_path');
```

For the URL with alias:

```
\Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
```

Comment: Does `\Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();` respect Drupal installs in a subfolder?

Comment: how would i do that for a not current path?  is there a way to get it from just a string?

Comment: How do I get the absolute path, such as this: http://mydrupalsite.org/node/123 ?

Comment: global $base_root;
    $current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
    $current_path = $base_root . $current_uri;

Answer (score 30):

In Drupal 8 you can do this with Twig:

```
{{ url('<current>') }}
```

example:

```
<a href="{{ url('<current>') }}">{{ 'Reload'|t }}</a>
```

from: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates

Comment: Great find @nicola-de-lazzari  - Also Your answers works in Views as well.

View > Fields > Rewrite Results > Link path accepts `{{ url('<current>') }}` even though not listed under Replacement patterns.

Comment: +1 Works in Drupal 9 (9.0.7) I have found. Thank you!

Comment: Note : to have the path instead of the full URL you can use `{{ path('<current>') }}`

Answer (score 20):

For getting the current path in Drupal 7, you use to use `current_path()`, but in Drupal 8 you use `$url = Url::fromRoute('<current>');`.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2382211

Comment: `current_path()` and `drupal_get_path_alias()` they are different functions.

Comment: This should be the answer as this version gives the path with the language prefix.

Comment: The OP is asking for the D8 equivalent of drupal_get_path_alias() . You are returning the current path and NOT the aliased path from the D7 'node/'.$nid

Answer (score 13):

To get current path (aliased path):

```
// Returns something like /about
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<current>');
```

To get current path (system path):

```
// Returns node/1
$path = $url->getInternalPath();
```

Answer (score 10):

To get full current url not just the path (Drupal 8), this is the cleanest solution I was able to find:

```
Url::fromRoute('<current>',array(),array('absolute'=>'true'))->toString();
```

Comment: `\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<current>', [], ['absolute' => 'true'])->toString()`

Answer (score 9):

In Twig template / Drupal 8 :

**URL of the current page**

```
{{ url('<current>') }}
```

**only PATH**

```
{{ path('<current>') }}
```

See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates

Answer (score 5):

If you want the absolute URL with the querystring too:

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
// ...
Url::fromRoute('<current>', [], ['query' => \Drupal::request()->query->all(), 'absolute' => 'true'])->toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the current route name:

```
$current_route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
```

Get current query parameters (upscaled):

```
$current_parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();
```

Get current URL as an object of type `Drupal\Core\Url`, which requires the query parameters to be an array of values rather than upscaled objects

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$url = Url::fromRoute(\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName(), \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameters()->all());
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Drupal 8.8.0, the path.alias_manager has been deprecated in favor of the new service path_alias.manager (see the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3092086).)

Accordingly, you can get the current path alias this way:

`$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);`

Answer (score 1):

To get the full current Url it is best to use this:

```
$current_url = \Drupal::request()->getUri();
```

`$current_url` will look something like this:

```
http://example.com/my-current-page.html?query_var1=1&query_var2=2
```