# How can I get the path alias from a node ID or node object?

Tags: 8, nodes, path-aliases

I have a node object, and I am trying to use it to get a given path in Drupal 8.

There was `drupal_lookup_path()` in Drupal 7 but I'm not seeing any equivalent or documentation for Drupal 8.

What's the new "Drupal" way to get a path from a node object?

Would it be something simple like `$node->get('path')`?

This seems like a simple question, but I'm just absolutely not finding any documentation on it.

Notice I do not want the path alias for the current path; I want the path alias for an arbitrary node, given a node object or a node ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current path alias or path?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106103/get-the-current-path-alias-or-path)

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate, check the linked question there are lots of answers.

Comment: The other question has answers saying how to get the path alias for the current path, not for a node for which the OP knows the node ID.

Comment: It's not a duplicate - I don't want the current path. I want the path given an arbitrary node object or NID.

Comment: Yes, this is not a duplicate, see my answer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To get the path for a node id use [AliasManager::getAliasByPath](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Path!AliasManager.php/function/AliasManager%3A%3AgetAliasByPath/8.2.x):

**Drupal 8**

```
$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$nid);
```

**Drupal 9**

```
$alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$nid);
```

See [comment from Felix Eve](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230746/get-path-alias-from-nid-or-node-object/230764#comment375929_230764).

Answer (score 37):

If you only have the nid, 4k4's solution of

```
$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$nid);
```

Works great. But if you already have a node object you can skip a step or two. Nodes actually have built in methods for getting urls.

```
$node->toUrl()->toString();
```

Would return the aliased url of the node.

toUrl() returns a url object. See here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x

and toString() is a method of the url object that returns the string representation of the url.

Comment: Note that `$node->toUrl()->setAbsolute()->toString()` will return the absolute URL, useful for sharing etc.

Comment: Both methods look equivalent at first sight, but there is a difference. Using `$node->toUrl()` will give you the full path to a node. This means you get the path alias, but other URL manipulations (e.g. adding a language prefix) will also be applied. The `getAliasByPath()` method, on the other hand, will give you just the path alias.

Comment: `getAliasByPath` does return the path without language prefix. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 23):

What about using [Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x):

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;    

...

$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid])->toString();
```

Comment: IIRC, the primary difference between this and using the AliasManager, is that this will also ensure that outbound path processors run, while AliasManager just does the alias lookup.  You can also get the `Url` object directly as `$node->toUrl()`.

Comment: Much better solution.

Comment: Broiken if installed in a subdir.

Answer (score 12):

Best way to get node URL from node object-

- **Absolute Path** : $node->toUrl()->setAbsolute()->toString();
- **Relative Path** : $node->toUrl()->toString();

It will also handle node language.

Comment: The question was about the node alias, this is broiken if installed in a subdir.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the load method from `path.alias_storage` to return an array of the alias details or boolean false if there wasn't a path found for that node.

`$aliasArray = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->load(['source' => '/node/' . $nid]);`

Comment: Will this load all existing aliases? I would say yes. In my case, I need all aliases.

Comment: `Drupal\Core\Path\AliasStorage` is deprecated in drupal:8.8.0 and is removed from drupal:9.0.0. Use the "path_alias.repository" service instead, or the entity storage handler for the "path_alias" entity type for CRUD methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the node alias url by **languages** dont forget to use the language like this.

```
$alias_url = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'. $nid, $langcode);
```

If you are using it in a class do not forget to use the dependencies injection  correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As per the new [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3092086) in Drupal 8.8.0 `path.alias_manager` is deprecated and `path_alias.manager` is introduced.

New syntax is as follows :

```
$url_alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'. $nid, $langcode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, as of Drupal 9.2, none of the current answers work in a multilingual site that uses path prefixes for language detection.

This is what I ended up using:

```
// Note: using dependency injection to get the language code.
$lang_code = $this->languageManager
  ->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)
  ->getId();

// Note: using dependency injection to load the node.
$test_nid = 1
$test_node = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->load($test_nid);

// If the node has a translation, load it.
if ($test_node->hasTranslation($lang_code)) {
  $test_node = $test_node->getTranslation($lang_code);
}

// Get the localized URL for that node.
$localized_url = $test_node->toUrl('canonical', [
  'language' => $test_node->language(),
])->toString();
```

Comment: Once you have the translated node object you can call "toUrl" without the language option.

Answer (score -8):

I was hoping for a more "Drupalesque" solution, but here's what I made myself to do the job:

```
  function getPathFromNID($nid) {
    $db = \Drupal::database();

    $data = $db
        ->select('url_alias', 'u')
        ->fields('u', ['alias'])
        ->condition('source', '/node/' . $nid)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchField();
    return $data;
  }
```

Comment: No, you should never be directly querying core tables like this in Drupal 8. Use the API like all the above answers.

Comment: One of the issues with this is if there's a core update that changes how these aliases are stored this code will break.