# How to get the files of a particular page?

Tags: nodes

I am new to Drupal, I want to edit the code of a particular page, let's say, www.mywebsite.com/login. Where can I find the code for the particular page/node. In static websites I could just navigate to the url and get the page, however, I am not sure how to get to the specific piece of code which is initiated when I go to the URL.

Please help with some direction or tutorial.

Comment: Hi Arihant, what is your drupal version? Did you want to edit a specific page?

Comment: Hi @JapoDomingo, I am working with Drupal 8. I want to add custom javascript to one particular page and for that I need to know where the files are. No clue where to look into

Answer (score 1):

The way drupal works, is these requests are sent to the index.php where they are parsed, the database queried, the content fetched and built for the page. Aside from images and files embedded, none of the files are accessed directly (I guess except for theme files as well).

What do you want to do?

---

Based on your comment, 
- you should probably implement `hook_page_bottom` 
- Then get the path with this, [Get the current path alias or path?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106103/get-the-current-path-alias-or-path)
- Add an if based on the above path
- add your JS to the `page_bottom`array

Documentation, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_bottom/8.2.x

Comment: I am trying to add a custom javascript to execute when the user navigates to a particular URL. Funny enough, I am not even able to figure out where the index.php file is because on my local installation when I open the index.php file, it talks about first time setup installation of Drupal on my localhost.

Comment: Where should I implement the hook? Which file?

Comment: Easiest place is in your theme's `.theme` file. But careful if it's not a subtheme because upgrading could overwrite these settings. Check these two links, https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/drupal-8-theme-folder-structure and https://www.drupal.org/node/2623936

Comment: This is going to be difficult to do without some basic understanding of Drupal and how theming works first. T isn't a static website.

Comment: There's a lot of documentation here, https://www.drupal.org/documentation Check which version you're using first. (Drupal 7 and 8 have significant changes)

Answer (score 0):

here's a good link:

[JavaScript API overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview)

And also check out the links at the bottom of that page.

And if you want to understand the render process:

[The Drupal 8 render pipeline](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/the-drupal-8-render-pipeline)