# Is there a way to serve a specific node for certain paths?

Tags: 8

I'm using Pantheon and there doesn't seem to be a way to update nginx/apache config.

One of my templates is actually a single page app, and I'd like to tell Drupal to serve /node/1 for a couple of URIs.

[Get the current path alias or path?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106103/get-the-current-path-alias-or-path) shows how I am able to get the current path in the .theme file.

Is there a way to serve a specific node for certain paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core has URL aliasing built in, and having multiple aliases for a single path is supported.

You can manage these at /admin/config/search/path (assuming you have the core Path module enabled).

Comment: I think we are only able to add one URL alias per node, but here:  /admin/config/search/path, we can add as many as is needed (one by one).