# How do I get my custom module controller logic to trigger on only certain url paths?

Tags: page-controller

Hi all I am very new to Drupal and am trying to write a custom module.
So my site has a bunch of different urls for example *example.com/users/3* or *example.com/articles/47*. I want my custom module code to run whenever the user is on a path that has *exmaple.com/users/..* in it.

The custom code is in the module controller and has some api calls in it using Drupals global user entity. Right now I got it working where in the routing.yml file it takes the path I give it and just creates a new page where the custom code is working `path: '/custom/page'`

How do I get my custom code to trigger on certain url paths?

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. create a custom module
2. Add a `hook_page_preprocess()` function.
3. Check the URL with `$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();` (See this answer for [more info](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/150100/56157))
4. Do your logic in the path match  `example.com/users/`

You could also checkout Event Subscribers below, but I'm unfamiliar with them.

For more info, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-modules/subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events